# Cloth simulation strange behaviour

Tags: animation, baking, cloth-simulation, collision

I thought of creating a napkin for a scene and started with a plane subdividing it to 40. Its a simple plane with no materials, textures or modifiers. I applied the cloth modifiers from the physics tab and enabled self collision keeping the rest to default settings.

Even without any collision object selected the cloth just crumples up on its own.

[image]

[image]com/giF83.png

here is the blend file : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14xmpw7HWBSs5hGiOXNs609RYpnqFPbZg?usp=sharing

Comment: this is "normal". Maybe you should watch some beginner cloth simulation tutorials. You cannot expect that for every geometry the default simulation just works as you want it.

Comment: can you share that napkin object and table with us? This often happens if 2 collision objects interpolates at some point and it will break the calculation behind it... Try to lower margins for collisions to minimum, try to place it somewhere else. If it shrinks on it owns, then your self collision must have too big margin as well

Comment: What I wanted to say is that if your napkin is too dense with vertices and your margin on cloth sim is too big, it simply creates a mess when 1 vertice is closer to another than is margin distance, due to that it will create an error

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry if the perspective is wrong, but the cloth is in the air levitating. and there is no collision object for it. I followed a basic cloth simulation tutorial on youtube and tried this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=252qhBFl2UM&t=752s this is what I tried.

Comment: @MikoCG Here is a link to the blend file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14xmpw7HWBSs5hGiOXNs609RYpnqFPbZg?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as I suspected, it is due to margin and distance error:

This happens with your settings:
[image]

And this happens if you change this value:
[image]

Your problem happens because the distance 0.015 is higher than the distance between vertices in your napkin(0.003 m), lower it down and it will suddenly work as intended.

Also, lower Distance in Object Collision if you don't want your napkin to float above the table

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This worked. Now I feel like I was worrying about something stupid.

Comment: No worries, it took me a while to understand all I know about sims and I still don't know it all. Just remember in any sims in Blender, if any of your objects will make something similar, it is always due to objects being too close to each other or their meshes are too dense

Comment: Thanks a lot again man. I'll keep that in mind for upcoming projects.